# iPhone 5 all outgoing calls fail

Tags: iphone, call

I have an iPhone 5 which I purchased (from India) in Nov 2012 and now it is out of warranty. I found an old SIM Card, which I purchased from Singapore when I was visiting that country, and put it inside my phone just to check if it still works or not.

I asked my friends to call me on that number, they could hear the phone ringing tone but my phone was not ringing so after that I switched back to my local SIM which was working before.
Now I am unable to make any calls from my number, all outgoing calls fail immediately with a "Call Failed" message and I can hear 2 beeps. I can receive Incoming calls, send and receive texts and can browse the internet using 3G data connection on the same SIM.

I tried the my local SIM in other phone and it works perfectly fine which confirms that there's no issue with the service provider.
I Tried some other local SIM in my iPhone 5, that doesn't work either.

This is definitely some issue with my iPhone 5. What could the issue be?
I am really worried because it is out of warranty now.

Comment: I saw a similar problem [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32091) but doesn't seem to help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution I found to this problem:

Open `Settings -> Phone -> Show Caller ID`

It'll take some seconds to load the and show a loading indicator, after that is done the phone will be able to make and receive calls

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem for call failed on my iPhone 6 was the bad date & time settings. My location-based timezone was not enabled, and the phone time was incorrect. I disabled the auto time & date, reinserted the sim card and BOOM!

I got the dots. It works.

Source: http://www.unlockboot.com/2015/10/fix-call-failed-iphone-6-plus-6-6s-6s.html

Comment: is any of them a permanent fix?
The caller ID and *#31# are temporary fixes, the phone restarts and it again does the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I tried

`Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Set Automatically Turn it OFF`

I set the Time Zone manually to the local time zone and set the time back to when I bout the phone in November 2012. After that I just changed the time to the current time.

After that I found out the Location Privacy Setting for updating the time zone was disabled in the `Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> System Services -> Setting Time Zone`. This must have happened when I switched my SIM Card. I turned it on and now IT'S WORKING  :D